# How can i cache data from API for 1 hour using Next JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I using Next JS.
I need to use `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` to do a call and cache data for one hour. And on the next page visit get data from the cache and not from API. After one hour again get data from API.

Can someone help with advice?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you need to use cookies with 1 hour lifetime , if you want store something big use Browser Storage